# clang-format: align comment style in the closing of preprocessor directives

Tags: c++, clang-format

In my project, there are two types of closing comments for #endif directive.

Example:

the first type

```
#define A
#endif /* A */
```

the second type

```
#define A
#endif // A
```

Can clang-format align comments to only the second type (C++ style)? Is there any variable to track a such setting?

I've only found [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) about bool `FixNamespaceComments` variable. It's only related to namespace issues. I try to find something close to this variable, but for directives or if there is not any clang-format method, could you , please, suggest how I can fix my issue automatically (not by hands)?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an option (up to version 17) that controls comments after #endif. In my case the code base has no comments at all so even finding the matching pairs is a hassle.

The `IndentPPDirectives: BeforeHash` option helps with pairing.

So this is not a constructive answer to your problem, but I post it, in case others also run into the uncommented #endif problem; their search may lead here.